# deploying contracts on private node taking forever

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, contract-deployment

I am trying to deploy contracts on a private geth node. I have mined enough that I have the account balance and the DAG was created.

Here is the netstats for the node :

[image]

Now, the contracts start deployment but take too much time. I am stuck for more than 20 minutes on this message :

```
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0x68c7b0fcefaf58e20607bfebe8e31bf2d490fa4474478f0ecd96e540c34d58d3
```

`testrpc` takes seconds in deployment. Can I make this deployment go fast in any way? I am deploying on the `bootstrap` node. Even though it shows `bootstrap` as offline in image, it comes back up in a second.

(Edited according to answer)
truffle :

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "172.21.0.6",
      port: 8545,
      // Match any network id
      network_id: "*",
      from: "",
      gas: 4710000
    },
    ropsten: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "3",
      from: ""
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: are you mining? you need to start mining first, otherwise the tx just stays in the pool

Comment: I started mining, then when the DAG completed and blocks were made, I stopped it. I dont think I can do both mining and deployment with same account as mining locks the account; which is why I stopped the mining.

Comment: you can mine and deploy with the same account at the same time. miners themselves can certainly send transactions :)

Comment: I am getting this now `Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.`. I have >600 eth and the error is still there. What can I do about it?

Comment: how are you deploying your contract? include the deployment code that failed if you can, please

Comment: I have edited question. Do you mean this code or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the amount of gas you're willing to spend in your 'truffle.js' file up to a max of 4710000.

Add the line: `gas: 4710000` to your network config.

If you get `exceeds block gas limit` the total size of the contracts pure deploying per block are too big.

Comment: I added the gas amount into the code, it still gives same error msg : `Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
`

Comment: Can you post your `2_migrations` file and the contract you're trying to deploy ?

Comment: Also you're SURE you're mining too right?  The mining is what actually adds your contract to the blockchain.

Comment: I got it working. I am using docker and the actual reason for the problem was some complication with the image instead of network issue. Now, I can connect to contract, but it just says : `[TXS] Pending: 5 from: bootstrap` instead of actually doing something. `bootstrap` is the docker image that runs geth. I kept mining when I was deploying contracts. Now that the contracts are successfully deployed, I have stopped mining. Is that affecting the usage of contract?

Answer (score 0):

Considering all the comments, it seems that you are not mining while deploying. EVERY transactions need to be mined. So start mining and that will do.